# Date converting to number on import from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, import

I am trying to import a table from Excel into SQL Server and there is one field that sometimes contains a date (`mm/dd/yyyy`) and sometimes contains a date and text (`mm/dd/yyyy notes`).

When I use the import wizard the rows that just have a date are converted to a five digit number (`#####`). The rows that have the date and text appear normally. There is another field that is only a date and that imports normally as datetime.

I also tried to write a import statement in excel like this:

```
="Import into MyTable values('"&A2&"','"&B2&"', [...] )"
```

But that also formatted the date as a five digit number.

Does anyone have a suggestion to import this field and preserve the date format? If that is not possible then can I convert from the five digit number back to a date?

Comment: I suggest that you change the format of the field that you have in excel to Text. In my experience, SQL Server will automatically import the field as text (DT_String IIRC) and that should leave the dates as is.

Comment: @Jerry Excel changes the dates to the five digit number as soon as I format as text. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hmm, right. What about exporting the excel first to a txt file, by tab delimiter through "Save As > Text (Tab Delimiter).txt" and import that file into SQL?

Comment: @Jerry Looks like this one works. Thank you! For anyone reading this in the future you need to select Flat File under data source in the import wizard.

Comment: I guess I'll add an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

1. First export the excel file as Text with Tab delimiter using Save As:

   [image]
2. Then open up SQL Server and in the import wizard, pick Flat File (that is the name SQL uses for raw text files, CSVs, etc):

   [image]

After that, just make sure that you have the right things set:

[image]

I highlighted the parts that are usually important during the import.

Comment: With fancy screenshots and everything. Very nice.

Comment: @Pat Yea ^^; I couldn't be sure how the data would react because sometimes I don't have it to see, so I wanted to make sure with the different options on hand.