# How to turn huge Excel sheets into a database?

Tags: database, excel

I have 12 very-large Excel sheets.

Each one is 102 columns wide, and an average of 600K rows long.

They're all identical in structure.

Quite often I need to run a specific query, from only a subset of columns, with a specific criteria. And the process of doing so by opening each file and filtering/sorting/finding what I need has become very tedious.

If they were all in a database, such queries would be so much easier.

I tried MS Access, and I tried SQL Server Express.

Both die on me during the respective Import wizards.

And the failure is certainly due to the size of the data set, because if I manually trim a file to say 10 rows, the import works fine.

Any ideas how to do this? I'm open to using Access, or SQL Server Express, or any other tool that does the job really.

Note: Some of the columns contain records that contain commas, hence several suggestions I found to turn the files into CSVs prior to import, ended up with broken structure.

Edit 1: They're 12 separate workbooks, with 1 sheet in each. And the aim is create a single table where all the data is appended.

Comment: For size, SQL Server shouldn't have any issue. It can handle way more than that; I've worked with +15M rows and about a hundred columns on SQL server without any problem. I think that the issue comes with the data types. In excel, those don't matter as much as in databases. I suggest you assign each column a format that is not 'General'. Use text, number, dates and such, except general. This will facilitate the import both in Access and SQL server. If that doesn't work, try exporting to a txt with TAB delimiters.

Comment: I would suggest SQL Server over Access here, 7M rows would be pushing it for Access. Anther question: is it just data or are certain columns formulas?

Comment: if u want to convert it to database first u need to steady the structure of the cols and rows if all the rows has same number of col then it would be more easy to convert to a Table,  

and whats the purpose of this this ?, so i can tell you which database tool to use

Comment: @Jerry txt with tab delimiters worked, I was able to import it after getting the "Suggested Types" to scan through 10000 records sample to identify the data types correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3503095 You're welcome! Also, that means it's similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22770342/1578604) :)